# How to align a button and verbatimTextOutput in R Shiny without overlap and linebreak when rescaling the window?

Tags: r, shiny, window, line-breaks, overlap

I am trying to align a `shinyDirButton` with a `verbatimTextOutput` in R Shiny by using a `fluidRow()`. The problem I'm facing, is that when making the window smaller the `verbatimTextOutput` overlaps with the `shinyDirButton` and jumps to a new line when shrinking the window even further. When I increase the window size, the `verbatimTextOutput` will not keep a constant distance from the `shinyDirButton`. I would like the button and the text output to always stay in the same line with a certain distance no matter the window size.

My code so far:

```
fluidRow(
   column(2,
      shinyDirButton("dir_out_input", label = NULL, title = "Select directory", multiple = FALSE, icon = icon("folder"), viewtype = "detail")
   ),
   column(10,
      verbatimTextOutput("dir_out_output")
   )
)
```

This is at normal scale:

[image: At normal scale]

When shrinking the window:

[image: When shrinking the window once]

[image: When shrinking the window twice]

When increasing the window:

[image: When increasing the window]

I tried many different solutions to this problem like using `span()` or adjusting the margins of the `verbatimTextOutput` but nothing really worked out for me. I also tried to use `style` and `class` variables, but I don't really know enough about how to use them properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I ended up choosing was to use CSS flex items.

```
HTML("
  .flex-item {
    display: flex;
  }
")
```

The flex items are defined with the class "flex-item" at the beginning of the UI. With the property `display: flex`, the flexbox layout is enabled.

Then I can call the flex items in a fluid row to achieve the wanted behaviour.

```
fluidRow( 
  div(class = "flex-item",
    column(width = 2,
      shinyDirButton("dir_out_input", label = NULL, title = "Select directory", multiple = FALSE, icon = icon("folder"), viewtype = "detail")
    ),
    column(width = 10, style = "width:100%;",
      textInput("dir_out_output", label = NULL)
    )
  )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

We can e.g. use `splitLayout` to create a fixed layout:

```
library(fs)
library(shiny)
library(shinyFiles)

ui <- fluidPage(
splitLayout(
         shinyDirButton("dir_out_input", label = NULL, title = "Select directory", multiple = FALSE, icon = icon("folder"), viewtype = "detail", style = "height:40px;"),
         verbatimTextOutput("dir_out_output"),
         cellWidths = c("50px", "500px")
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  roots <- c(wd = '.')
  
  shinyDirChoose(
    input,
    id = "dir_out_input",
    roots = roots,
    updateFreq = 0,
    session,
    defaultPath = "",
    defaultRoot = NULL,
    allowDirCreate = TRUE
  )

  output$dir_out_output <- renderPrint({
    if(all(c("root", "path") %in% names(input$dir_out_input))){
      selected_path <- do.call(path, c(roots[input$dir_out_input$root], input$dir_out_input$path))
      # selected_path <- path_abs(selected_path) # get the absolute path
      selected_path
    } else {
      "No directory selected"
    }
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your suggestion. Unfortunately, I have the button and the text output in a fluidRow column, so I can't use a fixed cell width, because above a certain size the column becomes too small.

Comment: @enrico-00 well, using `fluidRow` / `column` is causing the behaviour you are experiencing. If you are not willing to drop them, the behaviour remains... (it is called *fluid*Row for a reason)

Comment: I see what you mean. I also tried to use fixedRow but the problem remained. Isn't there a way to dynamically scale the verbatimTextOutput box sice or a setting for the fluidRow so that it doesn't overlap with the button and stays aligned with it?